# Vue JS Form data not sending to Django Rest database

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a project that includes Django, django rest and vue js. I am able to get information from the api to the vue js frontend. But when I try to use the Vue Js frontend to post data in a form after clicking the button, nothing posts to the django database. I've tried different things, but nothing works.  Appreciate any help thanks.

Here's my vue code:
AllNotes.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="notes_container">
    <div class="add_note">
      <form v-on:@submit="submitForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="content">Content</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="content"
            v-model="content"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button>Add Note</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="note_content">
      <h1>Tweets</h1>
      <ul class="note_list">
        <li v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
          <p>"{{ note.content }}""</p>
          <button @click="toggleNote(note)">
            {{ note.completed ? "Undo" : "Complete" }}
          </button>
          <button @click="deleteNote(note)">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      notes: [],
      content: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async getData() {
      try {
        // fetch tasks
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/notes/").then((response) => {
          this.notes = response.data;
        });

        // set the data returned as tasks
      } catch (error) {
        // log the error
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },

  submitForm: function () {
    // Send a POST request to the API
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/notes/", { note: this.content })

      .then((response) => {
        this.content = "";
        this.notes.push(response.data);
      });

    // Append the returned data to the tasks array

    // Reset the title and description field values.
  },
  created() {
    // Fetch tasks on page load
    this.getData();
  },
};
</script>
```

heres django serializer:

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from post.models import *
# Serializers define the API representation.
class NoteSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #journal_user = serializers.CharField(source="journal_user.username", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['id', 'content', 'publish_date']
```

heres my view in django

```
#For our API View.
from rest_framework import  viewsets
from post.serializers import NoteSerializer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

class NoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    

    
@csrf_exempt
def notes(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        serializer = NoteSerializer(notes, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = NoteSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your syntax for submitting an event.

**Instead of-**

```
v-on:@submit="submitForm"
```

**Either Use this-**

```
v-on:submit="submitForm"
```

**Or this-**

```
@submit="submitForm"
```

Comment: Hi Neha nope that did not work wish it would have worked. if you want to see my code more let me know I could maybe use zoom thanks