# Not able to Sumit data from Vue Js to Django Rest

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I built a web app with Vue js and Django, django rest framework , I am only able to post data from the backend. When I try and fill in the data from the form with vue js nothing posts. here is my code hope someone smart can solve this. Thank you for your help it is appreciated. I followed the tutorial from: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-vue-js-app-django-rest-framework/
I attempted it twice there may be some code issues with her code. but I am open for anyone to help thank you.

```
Tasks.vue
<template>
  <div class="tasks_container">
    <div class="add_task">
      <form v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" v-model="title" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            id="description"
            v-model="description"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tasks_content">
      <h1>Tasks</h1>
      <ul class="tasks_list">
        <li v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
          <h2>{{ task.title }}</h2>
          <p>{{ task.description }}</p>
          <button @click="toggleTask(task)">
            {{ task.completed ? "Undo" : "Complete" }}
          </button>
          <button @click="deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      title: "",
      description: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      try {
        // fetch tasks
        const response = await this.$http.get(
          "http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/"
        );
        // set the data returned as tasks
        this.tasks = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        // log the error
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
  async submitForm() {
    try {
      // Send a POST request to the API
      const response = await this.$http.post(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/",
        {
          title: this.title,
          description: this.description,
          completed: false,
        }
      );
      // Append the returned data to the tasks array
      this.tasks.push(response.data);
      // Reset the title and description field values.
      this.title = "";
      this.description = "";
    } catch (error) {
      // Log the error
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
  async toggleTask(task) {
    try {
      // Send a request to API to update the task
      const response = await this.$http.put(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/${task.id}/`,
        {
          completed: !task.completed,
          title: task.title,
          description: task.description,
        }
      );

      // Get the index of the task being updated
      let taskIndex = this.tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === task.id);

      // Reset the tasks array with the new data of the updated task

      this.tasks = this.tasks.map((task) => {
        if (this.tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === task.id) === taskIndex) {
          return response.data;
        }
        return task;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Log any error
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
  async deleteTask(task) {
    // Confirm if one wants to delete the task
    let confirmation = confirm("Do you want to delete this task?");

    if (confirmation) {
      try {
        // Send a request to delete the task
        await this.$http.delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/${task.id}`);

        // Refresh the tasks
        this.getData();
      } catch (error) {
        // Log any error

        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    // Fetch tasks on page load
    this.getData();
  },
};
</script>

App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <Tasks />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Tasks,
  },
};
</script>
<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>


main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

// set a prototype for http
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

vies.py

# parsing data from the client
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
# To bypass having a CSRF token
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# for sending response to the client
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
# API definition for task
from .serializers import TaskSerializer
# Task model
from .models import Task


@csrf_exempt
def tasks(request):
    '''
    List all task snippets
    '''
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        # get all the tasks
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        # serialize the task data
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        # return a Json response
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif(request.method == 'POST'):
        # parse the incoming information
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        # instanciate with the serializer
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=data)
        # check if the sent information is okay
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            # if okay, save it on the database
            serializer.save()
            # provide a Json Response with the data that was saved
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            # provide a Json Response with the necessary error information
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


@csrf_exempt
def task_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        # obtain the task with the passed id.
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        # respond with a 404 error message
        return HttpResponse(status=404)  
    if(request.method == 'PUT'):
        # parse the incoming information
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)  
        # instanciate with the serializer
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task, data=data)
        # check whether the sent information is okay
        if(serializer.is_valid()):  
            # if okay, save it on the database
            serializer.save() 
            # provide a JSON response with the data that was submitted
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        # provide a JSON response with the necessary error information
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
    elif(request.method == 'DELETE'):
        # delete the task
        task.delete() 
        # return a no content response.
        return HttpResponse(status=204) 

serializers.py

from rest_framework import routers,serializers,viewsets
from .models import Task
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'completed', 'created_at']
```

Comment: I just solved it.

Comment: my problem was on the Tasks.vue i had put some of my methods inside the methods: {} but had left some outside of the methods: { } so they were not being included. Hope this helps someone who gets stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS Form data not sending to Django Rest database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986045/vue-js-form-data-not-sending-to-django-rest-database)